# How to set a boolean to true and call it on an if statement in a different class with Android

Tags: java, android, boolean

I have 3 classes.

One of them have the attributes with setters and getters

On my main activity I have the `class nameClass = new class`

This My main Activity

```
coffe_cal coffecalo1 = new coffe_cal(); 
public void addf1(View view){ 
    coffecalo1.setFraps01(true); 
    coffecalo1.setFraps1(65.00); 
    showfrappeup(); 
} 

public void checkout(View view){ 
    Intent checkout2 = new Intent (this, check_out.class);
    startActivity(checkout2); 
}
```

and I have an onClick event that set my `boolean = true` but in my third class I have the following

```
TextView stuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.StuffTotal);
String SoutTotal = "";
SoutTotal += coffecalo1.TotalTicket();
stuff.setText(SoutTotal);
    }
```

On my TotalTicket method I have this :

```
public String TotalTicket(){
    String message = "";
    if (this.isFraps01()){
        message += "Frappuccino moka .................." + this.getFraps1() + "\n\n";
    }
    return message;
}
```

This is the onClick event :

```
public void addf1(View view){
    coffecalo1.setFraps01(true);
    coffecalo1.setFraps1(65.00);
    showfrappeup();
}
```

When I run my app the TextView doesn't show anything. There 2 different activities by the way.

Comment: Please use debugger or put log on `SoutTotal` and check  `SoutTotal` has data

Comment: It's not clear. Can you post more of your code? With the class declaration?

Comment: `coffe_cal coffecalo1 = new coffe_cal();`
`public void addf1(View view){
        coffecalo1.setFraps01(true);
        coffecalo1.setFraps1(65.00);
        showfrappeup();
    }`

`public void checkout(View view){
        Intent checkout2 = new Intent (this, check_out.class);
        startActivity(checkout2);
    } `
This is my main activity

Comment: my check_out class is 

`coffe_cal coffecalo1 = new coffe_cal();` 

`TextView stuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.StuffTotal);

        String SoutTotal = "";

        SoutTotal += coffecalo1.TotalTicket();

        stuff.setText(SoutTotal);
    }`

Comment: And my coffe_cal class with the TotalTicket method is 

`public String TotalTicket() {

        String message = "";

        if (this.isFraps01()) {
            message += "Frappuccino moka .................." + this.getFraps1() + "\n\n";
        }
 return message;`

Comment: Please update your question by putting more code there. Please don't put code in comments.

Comment: Instead of `startActivity(Intent)`, use [`startActivity(Intent, Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent,%20android.os.Bundle%29) and pass the boolean as known extra as part of the `Bundle`

Answer (score 0):

define the variable as a public static variable shall to the trick.

```
public class MyActivity {
    public static boolean myVar = false;
}


public class AnotherClass {

    public void someMethod() {
        if (MyActivity.myVar) { // do some work 

        }

    }
```